# Can you write a Lorentz transformation as the tensor product of a 4-vector with a 4-covector?

Tags: special-relativity

I was wondering if there is a way to re-write a general Lorentz transformation

[image]

in a Lorentz covariant way. Since one index is up while the other is down, I assumed that it could be written as the tensor product of a 4-vector with a 4-covector. But the only covariant quantities I can think of using are the identity tensor, the 4-velocity and perhaps the levi-civita thensor?

Maybe Lorentz transformations are not tensors. The trace of the matrix is equal to $2(1+\gamma)$ which does not look invariant.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html#c2

Comment: Lorentz transformations transform coordinates from a frame into a primed frame and are often denoted as ${\Lambda_{\mu'}}^\nu\,.$ In contrast, components of a tensor are meaningful only in the same frame: $T_{\mu\nu}$ or $T_{\mu'\nu'}\,.$ Therefore I am not quite sure why that matrix above should be a tensor, and even if it were one, why this is physically meaningful.

Comment: Note that a Lorentz Transformation has to be invertible.

Comment: Quantities with indices are not always tensors.

Comment: *Since one index is up while the other is down* You didn’t show any indices.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer.** You only have to change the sign to the elements on the first row and column, except for the element (1,1).

**Some details.**
Lorentz transformation allows you to find the rule of transformation of the coordinates of a vector $\mathbf{v}$ as seen by two inertial observers $O$ and $O'$ in their own bases, i.e.
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{v} = v^i \mathbf{b}_i = v'^j \mathbf{b}'_j \ ,
\end{equation}
providing the rule of transformation
\begin{equation}
  v'^j = T^j_i v^i \ ,
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{v} = v^i \mathbf{b}_i =  v^i T^j_i \mathbf{b}'_j
\qquad \rightarrow \qquad \mathbf{b}_i = T^j_i \mathbf{b}'_j \ .
\end{equation}

If you want to find the relation between the covariant coordinates as seen by the two observer, you first need to use the metric tensor $g \hspace{-4pt}g$ to transform from contravariant to covariant components
\begin{equation}
  v^i = g^{ik} v_k \qquad , \qquad v'^j = g'^{il} v'_l \ ,
\end{equation}
and insert in the relation above
\begin{equation}
 g'^{jl}v'_l = T^j_i g^{ik} v_k \qquad \rightarrow \qquad v'_l = \underbrace{g'_{jl} T^j_i g^{ik}}_{={T^{cov \ }}^k_l} v_k \ ,
\end{equation}
being the components of the metric tensor (special relativity, Minkowski metric) equal to $diag(-1,1,1,1)$ or $diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$ depending on the metric signature you're using.

This results in the result written in the short answer, i.e. changing the sign of the elements [1,2:4], [2:4,1].